# How do you automatically set text box to Uppercase?

Tags: html

I am using the following style attribute to set the user input to uppercase so that when the user starts typing in the text box for example `railway`, then it should be  altered to capital letters like `RAILWAY`  without the user having to press the Caps-lock button.

This is the code I am using for the input:

```
<input type = "text" class = "normal" name = "Name" size = "20" maxlength = "20"> <img src="../images/tickmark.gif" border="0" style='text-transform:uppercase'/>
```

But I am not getting the desired output by using this attribute.

Comment: As mentioned below, be careful having spaces between = and values "text"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Input to Upper Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757101/change-input-to-upper-case)

Answer (score 381, accepted):

You've put the `style` attribute on the `<img>` tag, instead of the `<input>`.

It is also not a good idea to have the spaces between the attribute name and the value...

```
<input type="text" class="normal" 
       name="Name" size="20" maxlength="20" 
       style="text-transform:uppercase" /> 
<img src="../images/tickmark.gif" border="0" />
```

Please note this transformation is **purely** visual, and does not change the text that is sent in POST.

**NOTE:** If you want to set the **actual input value** to uppercase and ensure that the text submitted by the form is in uppercase, you can use the following code:

```html
<input oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" />
```

Comment: Note that if you send this data through a POST, it will send it however you typed it, not how it's shown on screen.

Comment: @freefaller ,it changed all input to uppercase but inserting to mysql is lowercase text, how to change Capital letter!

Comment: @David, see the previous comment. The transform is **purely** visual. It does not change the case of the underlying text that is sent back to the server. If you want to save the text in uppercase you must transform it on the server before saving

Comment: This is not a full solution, since placeholder is now uppercase (which in most cases shouldn't be). There's no other way than using JavaScript.

Comment: @DavidJawphan, do a UPPER() on the value before inserting into the table.

Comment: Future readers that want the changes to be made on value instead of purely visual, see [Burak Tokak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37617376/3136474).

Comment: @DavidJorHpan You shouldn't rely on client-side behavior.  Always validate and sanitize on the server too.  Otherwise someone with a non-spec or malicious client could easily crash your site.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In additional, you can add culture info for other languages. 
**<html lang='tr'> or <div lang='tr'>**

Answer (score 133):

I think the most robust solution that will insure that it is posted in uppercase is to use the oninput method inline like:

```html
<input oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" />
```

**EDIT**

Some people have been complaining that the cursor jumps to the end when editing the value, so this slightly expanded answer takes care of that

```html
<input oninput="let p=this.selectionStart;this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();this.setSelectionRange(p, p);" />
```

Answer (score 47):

The answers with the `text-transformation:uppercase` styling will not send uppercased data to the server on submit - what you might expect. You can do something like this instead:

For your input HTML use onkeydown:

```
<input name="yourInput" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)"/>
```

In your JavaScript:

```
function upperCaseF(a){
    setTimeout(function(){
        a.value = a.value.toUpperCase();
    }, 1);
}
```

With `upperCaseF()` function on every key press down, the value of the input is going to turn into its uppercase form.

I also added a 1ms delay so that the function code block triggers after the keydown event occured.

**UPDATE**

Per recommendation from Dinei, you can use oninput event instead of onkeydown and get rid of `setTimeout`.

For your input HTML use oninput:

```
<input name="yourInput" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"/>
```

Comment: One could use [the `input` event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp) instead of `keydown` and get rid of the `setTimeout` workaround.

Comment: This works, but how do you avoid the ugly split second lowercase to uppercase jump?

Comment: @JonathanSafa you can't avoid it with this method, maybe you can have 2 input, one that you will be reading the type actions from user (which is hidden), and the other is for showing user, which will have uppercase version of the hidden input. But I don't think the jumpy letters are a big issue.

Comment: Going with the "input event" idea, adding this attribute to the `input` element seems to work well: `oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"`

Comment: @JonathanSafa Use this in addition to the `text-transform:uppercase` css style solution above to make the input always appear as uppercase

Comment: When a user edits existing text and puts the cursor somewhere other than the end, then the cursor will jump to the end with every character typed.  Is there a way to preserve the cursor position as well as transforming the text to uppercase?

Answer (score 22):

The problem with the first answer is that the placeholder will be uppercase too. In case you want ONLY the input to be uppercase, use the following solution.

In order to select only non-empty input element, put required attribute on the element:

```
<input type="text" id="name-input" placeholder="Enter symbol" required="required" />
```

Now, in order to select it, use the `:valid` pseudo-element:

```
#name-input:valid { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

This way you will uppercase only entered characters.

Comment: This answer doesn't work and doesn't make sense either. Why would a selection only if the input is valid affect the input text and not the placeholder? I guess if blank was not a valid value then this might work by chance. I used the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180140/make-input-value-uppercase-in-css-without-affecting-the-placeholder

Comment: My solution works great only for required text input fields. If you try to generalize it, it won't work. It answers the question above. You are probably asking a different question.

Comment: This is a really useful solution, and is exactly what I needed. It won't fit every situation since it depends on the field being required, but it's definitely handy to have in the toolbox!

Answer (score 12):

try

```
<input type="text" class="normal" 
       style="text-transform:uppercase" 
       name="Name" size="20" maxlength="20"> 
 <img src="../images/tickmark.gif" border="0"/>
```

Instead of image put style tag on input because you are writing on input not on image

Comment: That, however, also makes the placeholder text uppercase.

Answer (score 11):

Set following style to set all textbox to uppercase:

```css
    input { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Using CSS `text-transform: uppercase` does not change the actual input but only changes its look.
If you send the input data to a server it is still going to lowercase or however you entered it. To actually transform the input value you need to add javascript code as below:

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  event.target.value = event.target.value.toLocaleUpperCase()
})
```

```html
<input>
```

Here I am using `toLocaleUpperCase()` to convert `input` value to uppercase.
It works fine until you need to edit what you had entered, e.g. if you had entered ABCXYZ and now you try to change it to ABCLMNXYZ, it will become ABCLXYZMN because after every input the cursor jumps to the end.

To overcome this jumping of the cursor, we have to make following changes in our function:

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  var start = input.selectionStart;
  var end = input.selectionEnd;
  input.value = input.value.toLocaleUpperCase();
  input.setSelectionRange(start, end);
})
```

```html
<input>
```

Now everything works as expected, but if you have slow PC you may see text jumping from lowercase to uppercase as you type. If this annoys you, this is the time to use CSS, apply `input: {text-transform: uppercase;}` to CSS file and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

The issue with CSS Styling is that it's not changing the data, and if you don't want to have a JS function then try...

`<input onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" />`

on it's own you'll see the field capitalise on keyup, so it might be desirable to combine this with the `style='text-transform:uppercase'` others have suggested.

Answer (score 3):

IN HTML input tag just style it like follows

```
<input type="text" name="clientName" style="text-transform:uppercase" required>
```

in backed php/laravel use:

```
$name = strtoupper($clientName);
```

Answer (score 2):

Various answers here have various problems, for what I was trying to achieve:

Just using text-transform changes the appearance but not the data.
Using oninput or onkeydown changes the cursor position, so you can't, for instance, click in the middle of your existing input and edit it.
Saving the position works, but just seemed a bit kludgey.

It felt cleaner to me to just break the problem up into two parts: upper-casing what I'm typing while I type (text-transform), and upper-casing the submitted data (run toUpperCase *onchange*):

```html
<input id = "thing" onchange="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase(); pr()" style=text-transform:uppercase /><p>
<b><span id="result"></span></b>
<script>function pr() {document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById("thing").value}</script>
```

Type something in that, hit return or click out of the input, then click in the middle of your previous entry, add some lc text, hit return...

Answer (score 1):

Encountering with the cursor jumping to the end of the text. it is happening because you're setting the entire input value to uppercase within the event listener. To fix this, you should store the cursor position before changing the value and then restore it afterward.

```
<input type="text" id="someInput" />
<script>
    var someInput = document.querySelector('#someInput');
    someInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
        // Store the current cursor position
        var cursorPosition = someInput.selectionStart;

        // Convert the input value to uppercase
        someInput.value = someInput.value.toUpperCase();

        // Restore the cursor position
        someInput.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As nobody suggested it:

If you want to use the CSS solution with lowercase placeholders, you just have to style the placeholders separately. Split the 2 placeholder styles for IE compatibility.

```css
input {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    text-transform: none;
}
input::placeholder {
    text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
The below input has lowercase characters, but all typed characters are CSS-uppercased :<br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="ex : ABC" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input style="text-transform:uppercase" type = "text" class = "normal" name = "Name" size = "20" maxlength = "20"> <img src="../images/tickmark.gif" border="0"/>
```

I went with the style text-transform:uppercase thing from poster. Then I just did the uppercase thing in php as well. Some people working too hard with that javascript.

You were close with the style being in the wrong place. You were trying to uppercase an image instead of the input.

```
$name = strtoupper($_POST['Name']);
```

I don't know why I wanted to throw in some extra stuff if it's a php page. This is something I like to do make it smoother for the person filling out the form.

```
<input style="text-transform:uppercase" type = "text" class = "normal" name = "Name" size = "20" maxlength = "20" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"> <img src="../images/tickmark.gif" border="0"/>
```

That's assuming you're using PHP as the backend and posting to the same page you are on. This will keep the user from having to fill out that part of the form again. Less annoying for the person filling out the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution, This will also take care when a user enters only blank space in the input field at the first index.

```js
document.getElementById('capitalizeInput').addEventListener("keyup",   () => {
  var inputValue = document.getElementById('capitalizeInput')['value']; 
  if (inputValue[0] === ' ') {
      inputValue = '';
    } else if (inputValue) {
      inputValue = inputValue[0].toUpperCase() + inputValue.slice(1);
    }
document.getElementById('capitalizeInput')['value'] = inputValue;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="capitalizeInput" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this oninput in your input field:

```
<div class="form-group col-2">
<label>PINCODE</label>
<input type="number" name="pincode" id="pincode" class="form-control" minlength="6" maxlength="6" placeholder="Enter Pincode" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"  autocomplete="off"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Given that there are 14 other answers, could you explain how your answer is meant to be better than the others?

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your input(style="text-transform:uppercase")

```
<input type="text" class="normal" style="text-transform:uppercase" name="Name" size="20" maxlength="20">
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function upperCaseF(a){
    setTimeout(function(){
        a.value = a.value.toUpperCase();
    }, 1);
}
</script>

<input type="text" required="" name="partno" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a Part No*" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)">
```

Comment: How does this answer distinguish from all the one's already given?