# Make input value uppercase in CSS without affecting the placeholder

Tags: css, uppercase

Is there a way I can make an input value uppercase without making the placeholder uppercase?

Seems like I get one or the other. I'd prefer to do this cleanly just using CSS (JS last resort).

[image]

Comment: Pop your current code into a fiddle and show the HTML/CSS in your question.

Comment: take a look at this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Comment: Lol users will get confusion if the placeholder is in lowercase and the value they types would be shown in uppercase.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Each browser engine has a different implementation to control `placeholder` styling. Use the following:

[jsBin example.](http://jsbin.com/gubef/1/edit)

```
input { 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    text-transform: none;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    text-transform: none;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    text-transform: none;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    text-transform: none;
}
::placeholder { /* Recent browsers */
    text-transform: none;
}
```

Needless to say, this only works in browsers that can handle placeholders. (IE9/10+)

Comment: @ShyamBabuKushwaha - [Seems fine to me](http://jsbin.com/gubef/1/edit). Just arrange properties in the correct order. CSS 101 :)

Comment: I reworded your answer as we know it works, and added the jsBin link to it :)

Comment: Worked awesome. Easy fix when developing on iphone6 and forgetting to check iphone 5.

Comment: A quick note on the :-ms-input-placeholder.  I had to include the !important flag on it for IE 11 to render it correctly.  I haven't tried it on other versions.

Comment: I've just tested it in IE11 and it works just fine. I think you have another CSS statement overwriting the placeholder styling. If you wish, you could reproduce the issue you're having in a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) / [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Nowadays, `input::placeholder { text-transform: none; }` should be added as it's pretty well supported.  Details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder

Answer (score 11):

I know you said using JavaScript was a last resort. However, in this case it is probably more effective and simpler (also if you don’t use JavaScript, the value posted on from submit will not be uppercase), so this might be better and no additional CSS is needed:

```html
<input oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" placeholder="Enter Drivers License #" />
```

Some people have been complaining that the cursor jumps to the end when editing the value, so this slightly expanded version should resolve that:

```html
<input oninput="let p = this.selectionStart; this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();this.setSelectionRange(p, p);" />
```