# How can I have entry in caps in a text box without affecting placeholder?

Tags: css, html

I want my placeholder in Title letters (Like --Please Enter Your Passport Number) and my entry in all capital letters. It also contains some numeric digits.
I have tried this: [Make input value uppercase in CSS without affecting the placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180140/make-input-value-uppercase-in-css-without-affecting-the-placeholder)
But when I tried this solution, All entries on my page are in Caps. I want just one particular entry in caps.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a `class` ...

```css
input.separate { 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 300px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0 5px;  
    margin: 5px 0;
}
input { 
 text-transform: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0 5px;    
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<input class="separate" type="text" placeholder="please enter your passport number" />
<input type="text" placeholder="please enter your passport number" />
```