# Issue with input placeholder in text-transform

Tags: html, css

I wrote the code for an input form, in whose css I mentioned

```
text-transform:uppercase;
```

But in the form I added the placeholder as "Name".However when I view it in the actual weppage the placeholder becomes "NAME". It looks quite awkward on the page in capitals.The input and css are:

```
#textbox {
            outline:none;
            background:#732ab7;
            caret-color:lightgreen;
            border-style:groove;
            border-width:0px 0px 10px 0px;
            border-top:none;
            border-left:none;
            border-right:none;
            border-bottom-color:lightgreen;
            padding:0px 0px 2px 15px;
            text-transform: lowercase;

       }
```

Input tag :-

```
<input hspace="32px" vspace="70px" id="textbox" type="text" placeholder="Name"></input>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every browser has a different method to control the placeholder styling.use the below CSS to avoid placeholder styling

```
input { 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    text-transform: none;
}
```

Already someone [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180140/make-input-value-uppercase-in-css-without-affecting-the-placeholder) check this

Comment: Oh sure, should I delete this question

Comment: I searched earlier but nothing came, so I added this one