# Uppercase value in Kendo UI Textbox

Tags: kendo-ui

Is there any way how to force uppercasing value in textbox when typing? Not after value changed, but when typing.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/input-field-uppercase/

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS for that:

```
<input id="textbox" style="text-transform: uppercase" />
<script>
    $("#textbox").kendoTextBox();
</script>
```

[Example](https://dojo.telerik.com/ECOQivAw)

Comment: Please check question - that's not what I want. I need uppercased value, not CSS transformation.

Comment: It is part of the solution though. If you need the uppercased value then it needs to be converted when you post it or after the server receives it. Lots of different scenarios are discussed in this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100041/how-do-you-automatically-set-text-box-to-uppercase

Comment: You said you need it *"when typing"*, so this answer satisfies that condition.